# Get version number from the DESCRIPTION file in an R-package

Tags: r

Is there a neat way for functions within an R-package to get access to its version number specified in the DESCRIPTION-file (of that R-package)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `installed.packages()` perhaps.

```
installed.packages()['MASS', 'Version']
# [1] "7.3-57"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `packageVersion()` function:

```r
packageVersion("MASS")
#> [1] '7.3.56'
packageVersion("MASS") >= "7.3.9"  # Compares as version, not character
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Depending on how many packages you have installed, this will also be much faster than using `installed.packages()`:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(packageVersion("MASS"), installed.packages()['MASS', 'Version'])
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                                     expr      min       lq      mean    median
#>                   packageVersion("MASS")  315.500  336.111  392.9827  370.0415
#>  installed.packages()["MASS", "Version"] 4648.788 4811.913 7278.9214 4893.4105
#>         uq        max neval cld
#>   425.8515    796.667   100  a 
#>  5055.4825 235622.901   100   b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: For the CITATION file of my package, I customized it and used `utils::packageVersion("rempsyc")` to make sure the version is always the latest. However, CRAN check gives the following warning: `Reading CITATION file fails with: there is no package called 'rempsyc'`. It seems it checks the CITATION file before installing the package, kind of weird. Any possible workaround?

Comment: @rempsyc, "Writing R Extensions" says "It is desirable (and essential for CRAN) that the CITATION file does not contain calls to functions such as packageDescription which assume the package is installed in a library tree on the package search path.", but it gives other ways to get the info you need.  See https://github.com/bradlindblad/tidyUSDA/blob/master/inst/CITATION for an example that uses the `meta` variable.  If that's not clear, I think you need to post a new question.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about this! I tried it and it works! :D